# Repeated column mapping on JPA entity mapping

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea, kotlin, transient

I've lost an entire day trying to understand what is going on and find a fix. I have a JPA mapped entity that, besides other properties, has the following:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "xyz")
   data class XYZ(
      ...
      @Column(name = "status", nulable = false)
      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      private var initialStatus: XYZStatus,
      ...
    ) {
        @Transient
        var status: XYZStatus = initialStatus
            get() = initialStatus
            set(nextStatus) {
                ...
                initialStatus = nextStatus
                field = nextStatus
            }
    }
```

This have been working **forever**, since this class was first created. Now the situation is that everytime I run my integration tests on Intellij IDEA (Ultimate 2018.2) they fail because the Spring context cannot be created. The error is: `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: model.XYZ column: status (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`.

The bizarre part: this error happens only on my machine, only when running the tests from inside the IDE. If I run the tests via Maven on the command line it is ok. I already tried to change the field name from `status` to something else and the error just changes for the "something else" name I give to the variable.

I already removed and cloned my repo again. Already removed and reinstalled Intellij. I really don't know what can be the source of this error. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: When removing and reinstalling IntelliJ, I believe it still keeps some cached somewhere in your home directory, so if the problem is there, they wouldn't be resolved. Could you try to **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart** ?

Comment: I discovered that the code generated by the Kotlin compiler from the command line (using Maven) is different from that generated from inside the IDE. From the command line the generated code is `@field:javax.persistence.Transaction public final var status: Status`. The code generated by the IDE doesn't contain the `@field:` prefix and I think that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Looking for solutions to this same problem but I fixed it by unchecking `show default Relationships` when I want to generate the entity